# Isometry group, one parameters sub-group geodesics

Tags: lie-groups, geodesic

I have general questions about the group of isometries of a metric space.
-When is the isometry group of a space a lie group?
-when the isometry group is a Lie group, is there a relation between the one parameter sub-group of the isometry group and the geodesics of the metric space?

I am relatively new to these concepts, any piece of answers will help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are several cases I could give to answer this, but the two cases I would consider to occur the most commonly are the following:

- Any finite metric space, since all finite groups are (compact) Lie groups
- By a theorem of Myers and Steenrod, Riemannian manifolds have Lie groups as isometry groups. This appears as the first part of Theorem 1.2 of Chapter II of Kobayashi's *Transformation Groups in Differential Geometry*. Thus, if the Riemannian manifold is connected, and thus admits a global distance function, then the isometry group in the standard sense is a Lie group.

Every compact Lie group $G$ admits a bi-invariant Riemannian metric, and under this metric, the one-parameter subgroups of $G$ are precisely the geodesics through the identity. However, I do not know of any general connections between geodesics on the spaces acted upon by isometry groups and the one-parameter subgroups on that group.

Answer (score 1):

One very nice case occurs when $G$ is a non compact semi-simple Lie group (meaning its Lie algebra is a direct sum of simple ideals) with finite center.  In this case, there is a maximal compact subgroup $K < G$ (the fixed subgroup of a Cartan involution) such that $G/K$ admits a Riemannian metric with respect to which $G/K$ is a globally symmetric space and the obvious left action of $G$ on $G/K$ is isometric.

Also, the one parameter subgroups of $G$ (whose generating vectors lie in a particular subspace, $\frak{p}$= the $-1$ eigenspace of the Cartan involution) push down to geodesics in $G/K$ and there is a close correspondence between left multiplication by these one parameter subgroups and the geodesic flow of $G/K$.

Finally, I believe that if $Ad(K)$ acts transitively on the unit sphere in $\frak{p}$, $G$ will be the full isometry group of $G/K$ (Maybe you also have to throw in the Cartan involution, which pushes down to the local symmetry at $K \in G/K$, if you want to flip the orientation).

So for instance think about $G= SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ acting on the upper half plane by hyperbolic isometries.  The stabilizer of $i$ is $SO(2, \mathbb{R})=K$, so $G/K$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{H}^2$. $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is the *full* (orientation preserving) isometry group (up to quotienting by the finite center) since $SO(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts transitively on the unit circle in $T_i(\mathbb{H}^2)$ (it's just rotations!). This action corresponds (via the derivative of the map $G\rightarrow G/K$ at $e$) to the action of $Ad(SO(2,\mathbb{R}))$ on $\frak{p}=$ the space of symmetric matrices in $\frak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$, as you can check.

I've been told that every symmetric Riemannian manifold is a quotient in this way, so it seems that this is what happens more generally, which is neat.  Also, I think the compactness/ non compactness of $G$ may determine the sign on the curvature of $G/K$, but here I'm out of my depth.  All of this is in the book on symmetric spaces by Sigurdur Helgason.

Comment: $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not the full isometry group, even after quotienting by its center. Consider the transformation $z\mapsto\frac{1}{\bar{z}}$. This is an isometry for the upper half plane model. Other than that, a nice answer.

Comment: @RobinGoodfellow Ah, ok, the full group of *orientation preserving* isometries! :)

Comment: There you go! :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will need a few days to digest this...

Comment: Tim Kinsella, when you say "there is a close correspondence between left multiplication by these one parameter subgroups and the geodesic flow of G/K", the close correspondance is simply the action or is it more subtle?

Comment: Also, in http://www-sop.inria.fr/asclepios/Publications/Xavier.Pennec/Pennec.IJCV05.pdf, at the end of page 9, he says :"the geodesics for the invariant metrics on affine symmetric spaces are generated by the action of the one-parameter subgroups of the acting Lie group". He refers to Helgason, but i unfortunalty don't understand. He is talking here about every one parameter subgroup, not a specific subset... What is then the difference with what you said?

Comment: @Chevallier  There's a description in the book Ergodic Theory and Topological Dynamics of Group Actions on Homogeneous Spaces, by Bekka and Mayer, page 69.    Since left multiplication of $G$ on $G/K$ is an isometry, a geodesic through $gK$ has the form $g\dot exp(tv)K$ where $v\in \frak{p}$.  Maybe talking about the geodesic flow, i.e. the one parameter group action on the tangent bundle of $G/K$ is more subtle, but its in Bekka Mayer.  I'll have to think about why $exp(tv)$ projects to a geodesic for all $v \in \frak{g}$.